# script executing perfectly in terminal but not in cron

Tags: centos, cron

I setup a script for to take an mysql db backup everyday on a specific time, so now the cron is running perfectly it executing the script without problem but the problem is db backup file is not stored in the specific location,but while we executing a script manually in terminal it executing and the files are stored in the specific location perfectly.

I checked the cron logs it's shows all perfectly running, and i check the cron and mysql status it's running perfectly.

help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you post a relevant fragment of the script? Also, how did you put in the line in cron? What operating system? That info may be relevant, this smells of a PATH problem or something similar.

Answer (score -1):

Are you giving the full path for this db backup file ?. If not not I suggest you do so. Always give the absolute paths in scripts.

Share us the part of the code which handles writing this db backup file to assist you further.